# How does one modify the object itself from which an extension function has been called?

Tags: kotlin

So I am fairly new to Kotlin Programming and while taking tutorials, I stumbled upon the topic of Extension Functions. The tutorial had presented an example of concatenating three strings at once using extension function (say tripcon) as follows:

```java
fun main() {
    val str1="Three "
    val str2="concantenated "
    var str3="strings."
    str3 = str3.tripcon(str1,str2)
    println(str3)
}

fun String.tripcon(s1: String,  s2: String) : String{
    return s1 + s2 + this
}
```

The above code will give a correct output as

```
Three concatenated strings.
```

However, if I modify the tripcon() function as:

```
fun String.tripcon(s1: String,  s2: String){
    this= s1+s2+this
}
```

And subsequently modify the second last line in main() function as:

```
str3.tripcon(str1,str2)
```

It brings out an error stating *Variable expected* in the line:

```
this= s1+s2+this
```

So my question is, is it possible for an object which has called the extension function be modified inside it? Or are there other alternatives? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are immutable.  You can't ever modify a string, inside an extension function or otherwise.

Even if you could, you wouldn't assign a new value to `this`.  `this` is the object you're extending the behavior of. You'd then not be modifying that object, but trying to "replace" it, or something.  I frankly would have no idea what that would result in if Kotlin let you do it.  But it doesn't.  If String were not immutable, you'd want to do something like `this.setValue(s1 + s2 + this)`

`str3 = str3.tripcon(str1,str2)` works because `tripcon` is constructing a new String, and then you're assigning that new String to the reference `str3`.

Comment: Ah I get it! Anything residing inside the double quotes is a constant hence immutable. And when I assign *str3 = str3.tripcon(str1,str2)*,  str3 reference variable just "points" to another String object possessing a value of str1+str2+"strings."

Comment: Yip  You've got it!

Comment: It would be cool to do something like this: fun <T> List<T>.remove(element: T) {
        this = arrayListOf<T>().apply { 
            addAll(this)
            remove(element)
        }
    }